# What's the point of Meteor.setTimeout() vs just setTimeout()?

Tags: meteor

In Meteor, why would one use Meteor.setTimeout() over just normal setTimeout()?

What is the value of using Meteor.setTimeout() instead of just the vanilla setTimeout or setInterval?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `Meteor.setTimeout()` ensures that this code is Fibers aware. Read more about Fibers: https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers

Comment: Thank you, would you be so kind to provide an example on what kind of new things Meteor.setTimeout() can do with fiber as opposed to without?

Comment: You have to understand how node works and what fibers allow. Check this answer by Slava (A Meteor core developer): https://groups.google.com/d/msg/meteor-talk/uipZ9I_37AU/SimAAlYnY6sJ

Answer (score 20):

On the client, there's no difference between them.

On the server, when code is running for a specific user (for example in method calls), you need to use `Meteor.setTimeout` instead of `window.setTimeout` to make Meteor remember for which user the function should be called. In the time between the function passed to `Meteor.setTimeout` is called and when it's called, other users may have called methods on the server, chancing `Meteor.userId` to return their user id instead. `Meteor.setTimeout` will change back so `Meteor.userId` return the user id for the user the call to `Meteor.setTimeout` was made before calling the function passed to it.

It is a design decision.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation.