# Meteor delay in iteration through collection

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-methods

Hello i want build a delay in my meteor server-side method when i'm iterating over the collection.
Meteor._sleepForMs Method causes exceptions and restart my app every time.
Which approaches are there for delay a collection-iteration ?

```
 Meteor.methods({
 ....
 start: function() {
 let data = Strategy.find({}, {limit: 5}).fetch();
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
            mqttClient.publish("test", data[i].charge);
            Meteor._sleepForMs(data[i].duration*1000);
        }
  }
```

Comment: So, you want your method to wait until the iteration complete. Right?

Comment: no in each iteration i want wait data[i].duration times

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Meteor.setTimeout`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/timers.html#Meteor-setTimeout):

```
start: function() {
  Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
    let data = Strategy.find({}, {limit: 5}).fetch();
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
      mqttClient.publish("test", data[i].charge);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

and also see [why to use that vs vanilla setTimeout()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27852081/whats-the-point-of-meteor-settimeout-vs-just-settimeout).

**EDIT** For a variable:

```
start: function() {
  let data = Strategy.find({}, {limit: 5}).fetch();
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
      mqttClient.publish("test", data[i].charge);
    }, data[i].duration);
  }
}
```

**EDIT** You can do what you want with the RawCollection object, setting its maxTimeMS to

```
var rawCollection = Strategy.rawCollection();
// Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER should be sufficient time
var cursor = rawCollection.find({}).maxTimeMS(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER );
var myData = fetchCursor(cursor);

var fetchCursor = Meteor.wrapAsync(function 
  fetchCursor (cursor, cb) {
    cursor.each(function (err, doc) {
      if (err) return cb(err);
      if (!doc) return cb(null, { done: true }); // no more documents

      // use doc here.
  });
});
```

Comment: but im not waiting a fixed time, the collection has a duration field which inidicates the delay time (data[i].duration).

Comment: This initiailly waits the data[i].duration and then iterates the whole collection and publish it. The idea is wait data[i].duration for each row in the collection and then publish it. Another strange behaviour is the exception :  Error: connect ETIMEDOUT

Comment: i dont understand the last approach

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is the following, but after 30 iterations it not delays the duration-field times and iterates random value between 1-10 seconds.
By the way i have thousands of documents in my db.

```
var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');
                var future = new Future();
                Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
                    future.return();
                    let d = `${moment(data[i].t).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")} ${data[i].field}`;
                    mqttClient.publish("test", d);
                }, data[i].duration*1000);
                future.wait();
```